# variable ip , and connect with ssh

Tags: shell-script, variable

I have a .sh shell script, with this content

```
ipserver = "66.249.95.255"
echo "root@${ipserver}"
ssh "root@${ipserver}"
```

but does not work, my echo is displaying:

```
root@
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blanks in the first line prevent it from executing.

Do this:

```
ipserver="66.249.95.255"
```